What integers can be represented as the scalar sum of two squares?
$$m=ax^2+by^2$$
What values of $m$ are possible for $a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{N}$? I know about $p=x^2+ny^2$ from David A. Cox's book, but not about this. As far as I can tell, every number should be re-presentable.
Is there a rule? What numbers cannot be represented like this?
Thanks.
P.s: Assuming $m>0$.
EDIT 2: The trivial representation would take $a=m,x=1$ and then $y=0$ or $b=0$. Or symmetrically, the opposite. The question is, are there any other representations? Any non-trivial reprensetations?

Are there any restrictions, such as $y > x > 0$? If $x$ and $y$ can be $0$ and $1$, say, $\ldots$

No restrictions. The trivial solution is $y=b=0$ ad $a=m, x=1$ or symmetrically the other way around. This is sort of the trivial uninteresting representation, the question is, are there any others?

That sounds like a restriction. :-) If you could describe what you think of as trivial (I suspect there are more than you just listed), that would be very helpful!

Related to Brian's comment above, another possibly "trivial" solution is where $x=y=1$ with $a$ and $b$ being any positive integers such that, for $m \ge 2$, we have $m=a+b$. Do you consider these solutions to also be trivial? Regardless, please clarify all such cases in your question text.

Once you've clarified your restrictions you might compute the first few results and pop into OEIS.

You say you know about $x^2 + ny^2$, but that alone is enough to get every integer $> 1$ while keeping all three $> 0$. Simply let $y = 1$, choose $x$ to be the square root of any square $< m$, and set $n = m - x^2$.
